# How do I train a model to score sentences? (i.e. with BERT)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have researched a lot, but couldn't find something that I understand / fits what I want to do.
I have a database of sentences with annotated scores (these should act as my gold standard).
I want to train a model that learns how to rate sentences with this data, but I don't know how.

I also may want to use a pretrained BERT-model, but I've never worked with that.

My experience in coding isn't really that extensive and I often struggle where to start with the practical tasks that I want to do. I know the theory, but the practical part is my problem.

Can anyone give me a hint on where to start or knows some tutorial I can use to get started?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you want to use BERT to complete a regression task. You can simply use [CLS] as a representation of a sentence, add a layer of FC and replace the loss with MSE, like the following

```py
class BertRegress(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.regress_dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.regress = nn.Linear(self.config.hidden_size, 1)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, y=None):
        pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)[1]
        output = self.regress(pooled_output)
        output = self.regress_dropout(output)
        if self.training:
            loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
            loss = loss_func(output, y)
            return {
                'loss': loss,
                'output': output
            }
        return {'output': output}
```

Furthermore, you can design your own pooling instead of [CLS], normalize the data and add a `sigmoid` at the end